# Blender with python api

Tags: python

Hello I'm new in blender api. I know python good but I can't start to make some changes for example with Screw modifier. How to edit the source on this type or try to write own version of this modifier. I found definition in:

```
2.71/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_data_modifier.py
```

I found in doc
http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.ScrewModifier.html?highlight=type%20screw#bpy.types.ScrewModifier
but cant find in blender files the class implementation.

Comment: You'll have to edit blender's C/C++ source to change the behavior of a modifier, as [they are not implemented in python](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14321/599).

Comment: @gandalf3: You should promote your comment to an answer

Comment: @CoDEmanX It might actually be a duplicate come to think of it..